# Is it possible to install Android on a Motorola ROKR E6?

Tags: rom-flashing, motorola

I have a Motorola ROKR E6, which is currently running MontaVista Linux, and I was thinking of installing Android on it to make it usable again (and also to clear a lock code previously set on it that I completely forgot). I found how to access the bootloader, and now I'm installing the required drivers and software. But if I flash Android on it, it may brick the phone, so I'm going to be very careful while flashing Android. Do you think that installing Android on a non-Android phone like this old Motorola phone is possible?

Comment: Since there is no generic ROM for Android, I guess another question and hurdle is, is there a working Android ROM already for this phone?

Comment: Not possible. And phones of that vintage are useless nowadays (as phones), in a nutshell.

Answer (score 2):

Do not try this. Your best possible result is that you can't flash it. If you manage to flash it with Android, you will brick it.

The device has only [46MiB RAM and 120MiB](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Motorola_ROKR#E6) storage, which are *not enough* for Android.

There are a bunch of other reasons, why this isn't practical, notably that Android will not have device drivers for this phone, but the lack of RAM and storage mean they don't get to take effect.